# porting .net application which uses monitor to linux

Tags: multithreading, monitor

Looking into porting out .NET application to Linux. The application uses the "monitor class" for thread synchronization. I do not think Linux has monitor. What can i use instead?

Comment: Have you even googled this? Among the first 3 hits I got https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs

Comment: I am very new to mono so bear with me. When I run the mono analyzer, the report showed Monitor.TryEnter() is missing in mono so I assuming the code written using the Monitor class needs to be modified for Linux. Am I correct?

Comment: Looks like monitor class is implemented in mono. I wonder if the mono analyzer(moma) is in sync with the mono releases.